# Clarification for a rejected edit

Tags: support

I am sure there is a good reason for rejecting my proposed edit which gave the name of the film.  I would like to know what I did wrong so that I don't make the same mistake again.

A question was raised about why characters X and Y did something in the film. But the name of the film was not mentioned. I was familiar with the film, but I thought it might be helpful to make the movie's title explicit in the question. This is [the post](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84583/is-there-a-reason-why-nathan-uses-keycards-to-grant-or-limit-access-to-the-diffe) I am referring to.

[Is there a reason why Nathan uses keycards to grant or limit access to the different rooms in the house?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84583/is-there-a-reason-why-nathan-uses-keycards-to-grant-or-limit-access-to-the-diffe)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the edit rejection reasons explains this directly:

> Movie names shouldn't be present in the title. It is the wrong way to write a title with "`[tag:name]` title" or title- `[Tag:name]`

This is not how we tag films.

The film is already tagged with the film title. You can see it here:

[image: Image of question with film title tag circled]

This is why we have tags, to identify the film name. It's non-standard to append it to the title the way you did:

[image: How the OP edited the question title to read "Ex Machina: Is there a reason why Nathan uses keycards to grant or limit access to the different rooms in the house?"]

This doesn't mean that you can not put the title of the film in the title - many of our question titles do have it... but it's quite different to head the title the way you did and to say something like "How did they achieve this in [film title]?"

Comment: Thank you. Mea culpa. I guess I should have put it in the body of the text. The tags are obvious on my laptop but not so much so on smaller devices.

Comment: That being said, mentioning it in the question is usually a very good idea.